# How to access pages with a click through the menu

Tags: reactjs

It's been a short time since I started learning React, and I'm having difficulty accessing another page with a click on the Component Menu.
Following the React documentation, I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

export default function PermanentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Permanent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
        anchor="left"
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
          ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum
          facilisis leo vel. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit
          gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id
          donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit
          adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras.
          Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo quis
          imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. At augue eget
          arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem
          donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla
          facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac
          tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat
          consequat mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed
          vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. In
          hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et
          tortor. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin
          nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas
          accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </Typography>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which returns me the Side Menu with some buttons / pages.
I have already created the pages, but I do not know how I can by clicking on them in this Menu, to direct each one of them.
Thanks any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I the following Answer I used Variables and on the menu item click
>   it set the variable and after the make conditional rendering with help
>   of that variables

```
import React from 'react';
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
    import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
    import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
    import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
    import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
    import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
    import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
    import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
    import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
    import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';


    const Inbox = () => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1> Welcom To Inbox Page</h1>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    const Start = () => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1> Welcom To Started Page</h1>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    const drawerWidth = 240;

    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
        root: {
            display: 'flex',
        },
        appBar: {
            width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
            marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        },
        drawer: {
            width: drawerWidth,
            flexShrink: 0,
        },
        drawerPaper: {
            width: drawerWidth,
        },
        toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
        content: {
            flexGrow: 1,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
            padding: theme.spacing(3),
        },
    }));

    export default function PermanentDrawerLeft() {
        const classes = useStyles();
        const [showHome, setShowHome] = React.useState(false);
        const [showInbox, setshowInbox] = React.useState(false);

        function handleHomePage() {
            setShowHome(true);
            setshowInbox(false);
        }
        function handleInboxPage() {
            setShowHome(false);
            setshowInbox(true);
        }
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                            Permanent drawer
              </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Drawer
                    className={classes.drawer}
                    variant="permanent"
                    classes={{
                        paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                    }}
                    anchor="left"
                >
                    <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                    <Divider />
                    <List>
                        {['Inbox', 'Starred',].map((text, index) => (
                            <ListItem button key={text} onClick={() => {
                                if (text == "Inbox") {
                                    handleInboxPage();
                                } else if (text == "Starred") {
                                    handleHomePage();
                                }
                            }}>
                                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary={text} />
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>
                </Drawer>
                <main className={classes.content}>
                    <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                    {showInbox && <Inbox />}
                    {showHome && <Start />}
                </main>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but would like to know, what function does this "createHistory ()"?
And remembering: it's a menu, when I click I need it to display on the screen, without closing the menu. That is, in the Menu component I will set my pages

Comment: Your answer helped me a bit, now tell me, can I use an if in view? I would like to display the Home component by clicking Home, but I do not know how for a "If home clicked show component"  in html.  Thanks

Comment: you should make a different commonent of menu and call it in home and other pages you created

Comment: Or you one thing you may do that if you are working in one file then you should add variable and then make it false and when you press it then make it true and inside this compont you should use like this  this.state.ishome && <Home/>

Comment: My biggest problem is that following the documentation, this menu is like a function, and I can not use "state" in this function. So I can not do this: s

Comment: @FelipeXST I have to Update the in answer please copy and run the code it works for you